# How to catch if an view or UITextField enters editing mode?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I've subclassed an UITextField and inside that, I need to know if the text field is in editing mode or not. When editing mode changes from YES/NO I need to get notified somehow. I tried to overwrite the setter of the editing property, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that event in textField's delegate using `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method.

Alternatively you can add observer to listen for `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification.

Answer (score 2):

We have a delegat method of textField that get calls autoatically when the textField enters into editing mode and while its exiting from editing mode

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  EditingMode=YES;
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  EditingMode=NO;
}
```

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: cant get what exactly do you want to say. This is not my own delegate. This is textFields Delegate methods.